# Measuring time discount in scheduled services: is there a literature in empirical economics?

Tags: econometrics, regression

Prices might be different, for the same service at some date, if you try to acquire the service two weeks in advance and again at a closer date (e.g. two days prior to the scheduled date), such as hotel prices, plane tickets etc. Is there a literature on this? Something like a hedonic regression on prices using a regressor such as the quantity of days between the booking and the contracted service.